# View Report From Web Application Without Prompting Authentication - Reporting Services 2017

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, reporting-services, kerberos

My company just finish set up a reporting services server 2017.
The service run under a domain name.
At the same server, an IIS has been setup to run a web application in ASP.NET which will server the report from a report viewer. The IIS is currently running with default App Pool.

GOAL : We want client to be able to access the report from the web application without having to fill in the username and password from anywhere be it on intranet or internet.

Before this, we have ssrs 2008 with similar setup but for authentication we go with anonymous authentication, which is what we want, they can view report from anywhere.
But from microsoft site, they stated that authentication isn't supported anymore in the latest version, and we have tried doing it which results in error 401: Unauthorized.

Currently, I'm trying to do a kerberos authentication,
Things that I have done :

1. SPN for reporting services account.
2. Delegation for reporting services account.
3. Web application web.config I've added authentication mode="Windows" identity impersonate="true"
4. On IIS, I've enabled windows authentication and impersonate.

But when I try to request a report from the web application, I still got the prompt for username and password, when I fill in my domain and password, I still got the same error 401: Unauthorized.

Am I doing something wrong? Is Kerberos really suitable for my GOAL?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Sorry, If I am posting in the wrong section. I don't know where is the correct section for this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you are planning to deploy the reporting service on the internet its batter to use the custom authentication instead of the windows authentication. Creating a custom authentication extension requires custom code and expertise in ASP.NET security.

If you do not want to code a custom authentication extension, you can use Microsoft Active Directory groups and accounts, but you should greatly reduce the scope of a report server deployment. The following guidelines describe how to support this scenario:

- Create a low-privileged domain user account with read-only permissions. The account must have access to the computer hosting the report server. Provide a custom Web form so that users can log on using the low-privileged domain account.
- Create role assignments that map the user account to specific items in the report server folder hierarchy. You can limit access to read-only operations by choosing as the role assignment the Browser predefined role.
- Configure reports to use stored credentials to get data for the report. This approach is useful if you want to query the external data source using an account that is different from the account that allows access to the report server.

you could refer to the below links for more detail:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/bb283249(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#configuring-authentication-for-extranet-and-internet-access

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/security/authentication-with-the-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15

https://forums.asp.net/t/2095478.aspx?401+Unauthorized+SSRS+authentication+from+NET+IIS

https://forums.asp.net/t/1273411.aspx?Setting+up+Reporting+Services+with+IIS+Access+Denied+Error

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot for your answer. I will give this a look and see how it goes. Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it! Been head banging the wall looking trying to figure it out.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply. Sadly, not yet. I googled and found on how to create the custom security given by microsoft. My superior doesn't want to use that. the old anonymous authentication method isn't safe either so no reason not to use this one. This is the url, https://github.com/Microsoft/Reporting-Services/tree/master/CustomSecuritySample

Comment: @user5397881 could you please share how you are reading the report? how you set the user?

Comment: hi. thanks and sorry for the really late reply. After headbanging the wall. I got the custom authentication to work, using form authentication just like on the github. Though, new problem arise, as an Admin, I cannot add a new data source, when I click New data Source, I got error, ""An error has occurred. Something went wrong. Please try again later" and I can't click anything on the page.". Please help if anyone know the answer.